# Internet Explorer : how to detect the plugin is being updated

Tags: html, internet-explorer, plugins, activex

I have an ActiveX plugin embedded in webpages using the proper "codebase" attribute. The `'#Version=X,Y,Z'` is regularly updated. After a version update, every clients download the new version, as expected.

The problem is the plugin is quite heavy (~10Mo).

As soon as IE detects the new version, it triggers automatically the update, which takes a while. During the download, the `<object ../>` element is displayed with the classical loading picture on IE [image]

Users (not powerusers) don't know if there is an issue with the server, with the plugin or whatever. IE does not even display the loading icon on the webpage tab. There is only a message in the bottom bar saying : 'waiting for ....'.

How could I either display at least a text to warn the users ? Is there a way to detect that IE is updating a plugin ?

Thanks!

NB : tested under IE7 and 8. But I guess IE9 behaves the same.

Comment: check get.adobe.com/flashplayer

Answer (score 0):

How about this: create a  and add the warning message to the tag. Once the control is downloaded, you can hide the  tag and show the control.

Comment: ok with your solution, but my problem is : "how to detect" that the control has been downloaded... On the very fisrt download, this is exactly what I do to tell the user to install the ActiveX. But when updating it, I cannot proceed the same way